# Paypal Developer or Partner

Tags: paypal

Is there a difference between being a Paypal Developer or being in the PayPal Partner Program?  Should I sign up for the Partner Program?

I'm a web developer who has built an online store for a client of mine.  I built a cart that passes all it's info to PayPal.  I'm using the classic APIs.  I just started investigating updating my code and I came across all this partner stuff.  Should I bother with it?

Comment: You should ask programming questions here. You can find an answer to your question by looking at the paypal product pages.

Comment: Sorry.  I just couldn't find a clear answer there and the paypal site directed me to stackoverflow to post questions.

Answer (score 0):

If you're going to be building lots of apps on the PayPal platform I'd recommend [signing up to be a partner](https://www.paypal-marketing.com/emarketing/partner/na/program/index.html).

It gives you access to marketing material, logos, error reports for your apps, etc.  If you end up processing enough volume they may start giving you a small commission.  You'll need volume in the multi-millions each year to get that, though.